# Regex extract text within nested quotation marks [Java/Json]

Tags: java, json, regex, pattern-matching

One the following text, I want to extract the values within quotation marks, for example "hash".
The value associated with hash is from the beginning until the end of quotation marks, in this case:

> 00000e96c46d15aeaaf9ef6f88a295a8f17207d4cd9ac074d2314680095befc854d5a00600602af2fe03a24b61566ca2d8a6b858b0af840309ae449316833923

My pattern for this would be

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path.toString()));
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"hash\": \".*\"");
String nextMatch = s.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);
```

Explanation of the pattern: I look at sequence starting anywhere with a quotation mark, followed by the word hash and another quotation mark. Then a ":" follows + 1 space. Afterwards as many text until another quotation mark appears.

Sadly, this pattern does not work and I do not understand why.

> {"hash":
>   "00000e96c46d15aeaaf9ef6f88a295a8f17207d4cd9ac074d2314680095befc854d5a00600602af2fe03a24b61566ca2d8a6b858b0af840309ae449316833923",
>   "block": "{\"type\": \"block\", \"transactions\": [], \"timestamp\":
>   \"2017-09-07T07:09:52.628676\", \"reward\":
>   \"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\",
>   \"difficulty\": \"0\", \"nonce\":
>   \"feec6d57f31d8aee18889026e4e484d96de6b874013a1932018e809c60c45019033389671dcc2e3138a555705cec95e365d79d3e68a909efcf15d0d137770131\",
>   \"parent\":
>   \"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}",
>   "type": "block_hash"}

My entire code:

```
public class TryToStream {

    static String url = "SorryICantShowYouThatOne";
    static String charset = "UTF-8";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        URL getURL = new URL(url + "get?start_at=");
        int counter = 0;
        boolean inputAvail = true;
        //clear textfile
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("jsonFormatted.txt");


        URL tmpURL = new URL(url + "get?start_at=" + counter);
        URLConnection connection = tmpURL.openConnection();
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        JSONArray json = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)));
        //   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output2.txt"), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("jsonFormattedStream.txt"));
        bw.write(json.toJSONString());
        bw.close();

        Iterator iter = json.iterator();
        boolean flagForTesting = true;
        BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("jsonFormatted.txt"));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"hash\": \"(.*?)\"");

        while (iter.hasNext() && flagForTesting) {

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(iter.next().toString());
            matcher.find();
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            flagForTesting = false;
        }
        bw2.close();


        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

If I try to match the suggested regex, I do not get a match.

The result of iter.next():

> {"block":"{\"type\": \"block\", \"transactions\": [], \"timestamp\":
>   \"2017-09-07T07:09:52.628676\", \"reward\":
>   \"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\",
>   \"difficulty\": \"0\", \"nonce\":
>   \"feec6d57f31d8aee18889026e4e484d96de6b874013a1932018e809c60c45019033389671dcc2e3138a555705cec95e365d79d3e68a909efcf15d0d137770131\",
>   \"parent\":
>   \"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}","type":"block_hash","hash":"00000e96c46d15aeaaf9ef6f88a295a8f17207d4cd9ac074d2314680095befc854d5a00600602af2fe03a24b61566ca2d8a6b858b0af840309ae449316833923"}

Comment: Don't use RegEx. Parse the string to JSON and extract the value of `hash` property from it.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but sadly at some point the document does not seem to be json anymore, therefore I cannot guarantee its json formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is nearly there!

The problem with your regex is that it tries to match everything in the string until the *last* quote mark. So it will match all the way to `"block_hash"`. You just need to tell it to match lazily, so it will stop matching when it encounters the first quote mark.

```
"hash": ".*?" // notice the question mark!
```

Now this regex matches:

```
"hash": "00000e96c46d15aeaaf9ef6f88a295a8f17207d4cd9ac074d2314680095befc854d5a00600602af2fe03a24b61566ca2d8a6b858b0af840309ae449316833923"
```

If you want to capture the things inside the quotes, I suggest you add a capture group:

```
"hash": "(.*?)"
```

You can use this regex like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"hash\": \"(.*?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: Look at my updated code, I am still not getting a match

Comment: @InDaPond I don't think there is anything wrong with the regex. Try debugging your code, like printing the value of `iter.next().toString()`. If you still cannot solve the problem, try asking another question.

Comment: iter.next() returns something with hash inside, thats why Im so confused and started the question